# Share data between viewmodels | MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, singleton

Hello good people of stack**overflow**.

EDIT: Sourcecode is avaliable on:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yq4qbznl4b6gm4h/AADdjd_hb-OQXV5KL8OU5cbqa?dl=0
More specefic on I4PRJ4 --> Backend --> Backend.sln.

I'm currently making a productmanagementsystem that has a GUI. We've decided to use MVVM, and we're still learning it. 
Though I have a problem. On the main screen, a list of categories is shown, and the products in the selected category is also shown.

As for now, we've binded the data to an observeable collection. But the problem arises when we need to add another product, using a differen view and viewmodel. In that case we need to have Categories with data. We open the add-product-view through a command in the mainwindow, so to get the data to the viewmodel we have to pass the object from MainWindowViewModel to AddProductView and then to AddProductViewModel - and that's not the coupling I want.

So I tried using the singletonpattern, and binding to the observable collections as:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Backend.Models"
..
..
<ListBox Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static models:GlobalCategories.CategoryList}, Path=Name}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Where GlobalCategories is as follows:

[Models: GlobalCategories]

```
public class GlobalCategories
{
    private static BackendProductCategoryList _list;

    public static BackendProductCategoryList CategoryList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_list == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Made new list");
                return new BackendProductCategoryList();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Returned old list");
            return _list;
        }
        set { _list = value; }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, a messagesbox appears, telling me what was returned. But with the above XAML-code, it actually creates that object, which was my understanding it wouldn't do that and you therefore would have to initialize it yourself. It actually creates the object, and the msgbox will say that a new list has been made.

Though if I then do the following in MainWindowViewModel

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + CategoryList.Count);
    }
```

Then it creates ANOTHER list, but if I then do another operation, I get a "old list" message. What is going on - why is this happening?
What am I doing wrong? Oh - and the binding doesn't work, nothing is shown when I do this. And it's driving me nuts. I'm comming from a background in C and C++, and been working with c# and xaml for a couple of months - I NEED CONTROL. AND POINTERS :-D

I really hope you guys can help me out here, giving me an understanding what is going on, and how I solve it.

Or even better - is there a better way of sharing data between viewmodels? Because to be honest, then I'm not the biggest fan of singleton, and would really appericiate another soloution to share data between viewmodels.

Thank you so much for your help!

Best regards,

Benjamin

Comment: Can you give me the structure of the two viewmodel where you want to pass the data from and to. One thing that I think would help you is by using an event aggregator or messages. But I need to understand the structure of your view models and how you want to pass the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion on your end as to how property accessors work. Set and get simply allow you to declare members that look like regular properties to everything referencing them but are implemented with code. When something needs to access the list it calls your getter and is expecting that function to return a value (or null). Your current implementation is creating a new list and returning it:

```
return new BackendProductCategoryList();
```

But you're not setting the value in _list, so the next time the getter is called the value of _list is still null and you create and return the list again. And again, and so on. All you need to do is store it so that the list only gets created once:

```
public static BackendProductCategoryList CategoryList
{
    get
    {
        if (_list == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Made new list");
            _list = new BackendProductCategoryList();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Returned old list");
        return _list;
    }
    set { _list = value; }
}
```

One additional tip: don't call MessageBox.Show in accessors, you should be doing as little work in accessors as possible. Using statics like this really isn't a good idea either for a host of reasons, but I'll leave that for another question (look up "dependency injection").